# No connectionstring named '' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6

I know this is asked several times before - and with mostly the same answer. But in these cases the problem often occours when more projects are using same entity and connectionstring not being present in all config files.
In my case all is in the same project. And the connection string is present in App.config.
I am using a viewmodel in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ReportMapping.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReportMapping"
        Title="Title" Height="477.22" Width="836.631">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CompanyCollectionViewModel/>

    </Window.DataContext>...
```

I am calling my entity from my ViewModel:

```
namespace ReportMapping
{
    class CompanyCollectionViewModel 
    {
        NAV_HelpersEntities dbContext = new NAV_HelpersEntities();
```

If I call the entity form other places that my viewmodel it works. In example binding from code behind.

The connectionstring (which is working if used in MainWindow.cs):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NAV_HelpersEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Mapping.csdl|res://*/Mapping.ssdl|res://*/Mapping.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NAV\;initial catalog=NAV_Helpers;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And here the NAV_HelpersEntities constructor:

```
public partial class NAV_HelpersEntities : DbContext
    {
        public NAV_HelpersEntities()
            : base("name=NAV_HelpersEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<R_Component> R_Component { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<R_Configuration> R_Configuration { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<R_Masterdata> R_Masterdata { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<R_Type> R_Type { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<View_NAV_Entries> View_NAV_Entries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<View_R_GetAccounts> View_R_GetAccounts { get; set; }
    }
```

when I debug the CompanyCollectionViewModel constructor I can see that my ObservableCollection is being populated.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:
Allright I got it working for now by adding the connectionstring to machine.config. That works - but I guess it's just a workaround I will have to address later. Thanks for input.**

Comment: Not all projects needs connectionstring in their respective config file. only executing project requires connectionstring. in your case your wpf application would require it.

Comment: Yes. And the connectionstring is present in App.Config - but I still receive the error.

Comment: Post the connectionstrings in question. It is possible you have problem there.

Comment: Connectionstring added to question.

Comment: make sure you are not passing anything to `DbContext` constructor from `NAV_HelpersEntities` constructor. Not even empty string. I doubt as it says **connection string named ''** is not found.

Comment: The error is exactly :"No connection string named 'NAV_HelpersEntities' could be found in the application config file.".

Comment: Could you please add the constructor code of your `NAV_HelpersEntities` class?

Comment: @Herdo NAV_HelpersEntities constructor added to question

Comment: Could you give this a try: Remove the "name=" from the base constructor call.

Comment: @Herdo. Yes - then I get this: "Error 1 Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then remove the code that throws this exception."

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I have tried that - see comment above yours for the error I get when I do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a simple solution for that. You have to remove "name=" from the parameter string when you call entities constructor's base constructor.
So you have to change this:

```
public partial class SalesContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public SalesContext() 
        : base("name=SalesContext") 
    { 
    }
```

to this:

```
public partial  class SalesContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public SalesContext() 
        : base("SalesContext") 
    { 
    }
```

See it on here: [Entity Framework MVVM Walk Through 1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/entity-framework-mvvm-walk-959bb749)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
base("name=NAV_HelpersEntities")
```

to this:

```
base(nameOrConnectionString: "NAV_HelpersEntities")
```

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) a description of how to format code in your answers.